# Conversion to ecliptic coordinates in Astropy

Tags: python, astropy

I'm new to astropy, and trying to grasp the coordinate conversion module.

I started with some simple jobs similar to those that can be found in the documentation. For example:

```
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

c_gal = SkyCoord(l=0.0*u.degree, b=90.0*u.degree, frame='galactic')

print(c_gal.fk5)
```

gives the correct value of the galactic north pole in the FK5 catalog. This is an Equatorial Reference Frame, but how can I make the conversion to an Ecliptic Reference Frame, instead? I couldn't find a similar method that does the job. There is the general transform_to() method, but the problem is that I haven't been able to find a complete list of the available frames. Apparently, all the documentation and/or examples stick to a few of them, namely: galactic, fk4/5, icrs, which are all Equatorial and Galactic ones.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not in the documentation, you can always resort to manually checking all the attributes of an object. From an interactive python shell, if you do

```
import astropy.coordinates as co
dir(co)
```

It will print all the attributes of the `coordinates` objects. It's a long list and I don't know enough about astropy or astronomical coordinates to know exactly what you need, so here's a subset of what gets printed:

```
'CIRS', 'FK4', 'FK4NoETerms', 'FK5', 'GCRS', 'Galactic', 'GalacticLSR', 'Galactocentric', 'GenericFrame', 'GeocentricMeanEcliptic', 'GeocentricTrueEcliptic', 'HCRS', 'HeliocentricEclipticIAU76', 'HeliocentricMeanEcliptic', 'HeliocentricTrueEcliptic', 'ICRS', 'ITRS',
```

Perhaps `GeocentricTrueEcliptic` is what you need?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I had already tried to do a dir() of the class; for example I tried `print(c_gal.transform_to('BarycentricMeanEcliptic'))` but the answer was `ValueError: Transform 'frame' must be a frame name, class, or instance`. Then, in the documentation, I noticed that this class has an attribute called "name", whose value is `barycentricmeanecliptic`. So I discovered that `print(c_gal.transform_to('barycentricmeanecliptic'))` saves the day. In practice you have to call the method with the frame **name**, which you find in the class attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to deal with the same issue as originally posted. Here an example that converts 3 equatorial coordinates into ecliptic ones:

```
 from astropy import units as u
 from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

 raval=[112.357708,122.580465,104.726966] 
 decval=[-12.69596,-5.513852,-10.580455]
 coord_eq = SkyCoord(ra=raval*u.degree, dec=decval*u.degree, frame='icrs')
 coord_ecl=coord_eq.transform_to('geocentricmeanecliptic')
 latval=coord_ecl.lat.degree
 longval=coord_ecl.lon.degree
 print(latval,longval)
```

Note that this result is only correct for objects outside of the solar system; for those inside our system, more input info about distance etc. is needed